# sum up the results in window function:postgres

Tags: postgresql

When running my query I receive a result set which I would like to aggregate and show in two different columns. This result set itself is derived from different aggregate functions and window functions.

Here is my query

```
select user_created, 
       extract(day from creation_date) as date, 
       min(balance_cents/100::float) as balance,
       extract(day from creation_date)-lag(extract(day from creation_date),1) 
                                       OVER (partition by user_created) as diff,
       case when (lag(min(balance_cents/100::float)) over (partition by user_created))>0 
            then (extract(day from creation_date)-lag(extract(day from creation_date),1) 
                                                  OVER (partition by user_created))
                                                  *(lag(min(balance_cents/100::float)) 
                                                    over (partition by user_created))
                                                  *0.004/360
            else (extract(day from creation_date)-lag(extract(day from creation_date),1) 
                                                  OVER (partition by user_created))
                                                  *(lag(min(balance_cents/100::float)) 
                                                  over (partition by user_created))
                                                  *0.0849/360 
            END wish_to_sum
from     table
where    creation_date>'2017-06-01' and user_created in ('1')
group by 1,2
ORDER BY 2
```

And the result set is this table

```
user_created    date    balance day_diff    wish_to_sum
1                  1    404.66  null          null
1                  3    392.41  2             0.008992444
1                  7    295.41  4             0.017440444
1                  10   275.41  3             0.009847
1                  13   155.24  3             0.009180333
1                  15   151.74  2             0.003449778
1                  20   11.15   5             0.00843
1                  21   -5.15   1             0.000123889
1                  23   31.15   2            -0.002429083
```

I would like to sum the last column by summing the positive and negative values separately and display them in two columns.So, my expected result is

```
user_created            Pos            Neg
10/24/2014 18:51    0.057463889    -0.002429083
```

When trying to remove the 2,3,4 columns and aggregate the wish_to_sum column, it displays an error message saying that `SUM` function cannot be used with window function.

How can I aggregate my results?

Comment: can you create a simplified table with simplified data and just show us your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but when you removed the fields from the projection, did you alter the group by to only the first column?

Also, I guess you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
  USER_CREATED,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WISH_TO_SUM >= 0 THEN WISH_TO_SUM ELSE 0 END) AS POS,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WISH_TO_SUM < 0 THEN WISH_TO_SUM ELSE 0 END) AS NEG
FROM (
  SELECT
    USER_CREATED,
    CASE
      WHEN (LAG(MIN(BALANCE_CENTS / 100 ::FLOAT)) OVER(PARTITION BY USER_CREATED)) > 0 THEN
        (EXTRACT(DAY FROM CREATION_DATE) - LAG(EXTRACT(DAY FROM CREATION_DATE), 1) OVER(PARTITION BY USER_CREATED)) * (LAG(MIN(BALANCE_CENTS / 100 ::FLOAT)) OVER(PARTITION BY USER_CREATED)) * 0.004 / 360
      ELSE (EXTRACT(DAY FROM CREATION_DATE) - LAG(EXTRACT(DAY FROM CREATION_DATE), 1) OVER(PARTITION BY USER_CREATED)) * (LAG(MIN(BALANCE_CENTS / 100 ::FLOAT)) OVER(PARTITION BY USER_CREATED)) * 0.0849 / 360
    END WISH_TO_SUM
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE CREATION_DATE > '2017-06-01'
    AND USER_CREATED IN ('1')
)
GROUP BY 1
```

*If that doesn't work on the fly I'm sorry. I am not used to work with Postgress and couldn't test the code.*